# Implementing an responseHandler interface

Tags: java, web-services, apache, httpclient

I am implementing httpclient response handler. The call which is being made is `post` like this

`result = httpclient.execute(httppost, responsehandler);`

now i want to implement my responsehandler. so that i can fetch the status code of my response. I am only interested in status code i.e. 200, 404, 403 and then i want to send this response as *int* value back

something like

```
public class MyResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler<Integer> {

    public Integer handleResponse(HttpResponse respons) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
```

Now the problem is, i don't see any `response.getStatusCode()` method in response object. How to get the status code of my WS call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()`.

- [`HttpResponse#getStatusLine()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getStatusLine%28%29)
- [`StatusLine#getStatusCode()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/StatusLine.html#getStatusCode%28%29)

Comment: Read the API docs. I don't know the `HttpClient` API, but I was able to answer this for you by Googling for the JavaDocs.

Comment: I did but probably i wasn't focusing or panicing because of deadline. I didn't want to waste time so thought to put up here while i keep my search on and believe it or not, I had already implemented the method before i saw your reply. Thanks Anyways